# Add a text under item name based on checkbox custom field in Woocommerce checkout

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, custom-fields

I have a custom function that checks if a checkbox is checked and if so, it adds 'with vat relief' next to the price. If it isn't checked, it adds 'inc vat' next to the price. That works fine and my code is:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'conditional_price_suffix', 20, 2 );
function conditional_price_suffix( $price, $product ) {
   $isTaxRelefe = get_post_meta($product->id, 'disability_exemption', true);

   if ($isTaxRelefe == 'yes')
       $price .= ' ' . __('with vat relief');

    else $price .= ' ' . __('inc vat');

   return $price;
}
```

What I need to do now is add another function targeting the checkout page that says if the checkbox is checked show some text underneath the product title but I'm struggling. My initial thought was to edit the /checkout/review-order so I added an if else statement to output something next to the product title is. I added:

```
$isTaxRelefe = get_post_meta($product->id, 'disability_exemption', true);

if ($isTaxRelefe == 'yes') {
   $content .= 'VAT RELIEF AVAILABLE';    
}
```

but this does nothing, I have tried various variations, changing to echo statements etc. but no luck. I'm sure I am just writing this incorrectly. Can anyone advise? What I'm not very up on are WordPress functions as in if I could write one to target the checkout page only, Im not sure how it determines where to output your. an if else statement seemed like the obvious choice but not having any luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is a bit outdated and you should use `$product->get_id()` since Woocommerce 3 in your first function instead of `$product->id` in the `get_post_meta()` function.

You can also use instead the `WC_Data` method `get_meta()` from the product object directly.

Below is your revisited code with the additional hooked function that will display conditionally **"VAT RELIEF AVAILABLE"** text under the product title in checkout page: 
 *(without overriding the template `review-order.php`)*

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'conditional_price_suffix', 20, 2 );
function conditional_price_suffix( $price, $product ) {
    if ( $product->get_meta('disability_exemption') === 'yes')
        $price .= ' ' . __('with vat relief');
    else
        $price .= ' ' . __('inc vat');

   return $price;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_cart_item_quantity', 'custom_text_below_checkout_product_title', 20, 3 );
function custom_text_below_checkout_product_title( $quantity_html, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ){
    if ( $cart_item['data']->get_meta('disability_exemption') === 'yes' )
        $quantity_html .= '<br>' . __('VAT RELIEF AVAILABLE');

    return $quantity_html;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (active theme). Tested and works.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Loic, that works perfectly. Thanks so much. I have been scratching my head withjthis for a couple of days now.